# configure outgoing ipv6 with systemd-networkd

Tags: ipv6, systemd

I have the following systemd-network config and want to set the outgoing ipv6 address:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff

[Network]
DNS=2001:4860:4860::8888
DNS=2001:4860:4860::8844

Gateway=2a01:123:123:123::2

[Address]
Address=2a01:123:123:123::118/64
HomeAddress=true

[Address]
Address=2a01:123:123:123::122/64

[Address]
Address=2a01:123:123:123::100/64
```

Problem is, that the outgoing address is not the one I prefer - I want the 118 address but it is the 100 address.

I tested to set it as home like [mentioned there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437614/set-primary-ipv6-address). The home is set in `ip a s` output - but it dont works.

I know I need the default route with the src address - but dont know how to do it in the systemd way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer:

```
[Route]
Destination=::/0
Gateway=2a01:123:123:123::2
PreferredSource=2a01:123:123:123::118
```